# acceder a una fila de una tabla relacionada por medio de tabla intermedia

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buenas tardes mi consulta es la siguiente

tengo una tabla

```
Tabla 1
  Remitos
    id
```

Tabla 2 (se relaciona con la tabla 1 por idRemito)

```
   Detalle
    id
    idRemito
    idArt
```

Tabla 3 (se relaciona con Detalle por idArt)

```
 Articulos 
  -id 
  -idArt
```

hice esta relacion en mi modelo Remito

```
public function articulos(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Articulo::class, 'detalle', 'idRemito', 'idArt');
}
```

pero cuando quiero hacer una consulta para ver 1 solo articulo, me trae todos los artículos que tuvo ese remito

esta en mi consulta

```
 $remitos = REMITO::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')

           ->whereHas('articulos', function ($query) use ($producto) {
                 if ($producto) {
                    $query->where('idArt', $producto);
             }
            })
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. ¿Y cuál de todos debería traer? ¿Has probado con [limit](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#limit-and-offset)?

Comment: Si probé con limit(1) pero siguió igual, si yo quisiera por ejempor en el remito 123 filtrar por Piedra1030, me gustaría que no mostrara los demas articulos, ya que es un solo remito pero con 4 articulos

Comment: Si quieres filtrar por más columna, simplemente agrega un `AND` en la parte del `WHERE`. [Revisa la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses) donde hay ejemplo de pasar varios criterios `WHERE`.

Comment: gracias por comentar pero sería cual condición? porque yo lo estoy filtrando por id de articulo que al no repetirse no se deberian mostrar los demas? no se honestamente que pasa, desde ayer estoy luchando con eso

Comment: Tú estás filtrando por id de artículo sin más, eso hará que te traiga todos los que tengan ese id, si quieres acotar más los resultados, debes agregar aquellas condiciones precisas para ello, por eso te pregunté que cuál de todos debía mostrarse, si dices que quieres los que tengan `Piedra1030` entonces, debes poner el `where` así más o menos: **`->where('idArt', '=', 123)->where('Material', '=', 'Piedra1030')`** es un ejemplo, en vez de los valores `123` y `Piedra1030` que he puesto a mano, puedes poner las variables que tienes en tu contexto.

Comment: Tendrías que agregar un `with` con la clausula de restriccion. Igual fijate como estás debugando, porque en esa consulta no estás pidiendo los artículos relacionados, así que no sé de donde sale lo que muestras en la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `whereHas` se traduce a una cláusula `EXISTS` en mysql. Tu código  significa: "tráeme los remitos para los cuales exista al menos una tupla idRemito-idArt en la tabla pivote (donde idArt es $proucto)". Pero no le estás diciendo que filtre el resultado acotado a esa tupla.

Debieras añadir el uso de `with`

```
$remitos = Remitos::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->when(
        $producto,
        function ($query) use ($producto) {
            return $query->with([
                'articulos' => fn ($q) => $q->where('idArt', $producto)
                ])
                ->whereHas('articulos', function ($q) use ($producto) {
                    return $q->where('idArt', $producto);
                });
        }
    );
```

(cambié el `if` por un `when`).

Ahí dice:

- tráeme los Remitos que tengan un artículo con `idArt`
- con sus respectivos artículos, pero sólo los artículos que coincidan con `idArt`.

Si pusieras sólo lo segundo (o sea quitando el `whereHas` te traería todos los Remitos, sólo que algunos vendrían sin artículos.